# Linking parameter in URL to do required function in java

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a java web service which executes a batch file. I have finished my controller class. In the controller class, there is a parameter and the variable is `String fileName`. I am not sure how to code to make the `fileName` to carry out its function.

I will show my codes then explain about what `fileName` is supposed to do.

**RunBatchFile.java**

```
public ResultFormat runBatch(String fileName) {

    String var = fileName;
    String filePath = ("C:/Users/attsuap1/Desktop" + var);
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath);

        int exitVal = p.waitFor();

        return new ResultFormat(exitVal == 0);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ResultFormat(false);
    }
}
```

**BatchFileController.java**

```
private static final String template = "Sum, %s!";  

@RequestMapping("/runbatchfileparam/{param}")
public ResultFormat runbatchFile(@PathVariable("param") String fileName) {
    RunBatchFile rbf = new RunBatchFile();
    return rbf.runBatch(fileName);
}
```

When the user types in `http://localhost:8080/runbatchfileparam/test.bat` as URL, the test.bat file must be executed. When the user types in test123.bat instead of test.bat, the test123.batch file must be executed. Therefore i cannot code the String filePath to be `"C:/Users/attsuap1/Desktop/test.bat"` as that will execute the test.bat file. I want to allow users to choose the batch file that they want to execute. I think this is simple to achieve however i am not sure on how to do that.

How do i code to link the `String fileName` variable to make it carry out what it is supposed to do? I tried some ways however they do not give the results that i want.

Someone please do help me thank you so much.

Comment: Does the value of `fileName` begin with a separator (`\ ` or `/`)? If not, you're concatenating the name to the path to get "Desktoptest.bat".

Comment: I do not want that. How should i change it

Comment: I want the fileName to just be a parameter which will allow user to choose which batch file they want to execute. Now i have two batch files (test.bat and test123.bat). I do not want to code as `C:/Users/attsuap1/Desktop/test.bat` as this will directly execute the test.bat file and there will be no point of having a parameter

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou so yes it has a separator i do not want it to be concatenated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have already done the job here.

There are two ways that you can execute the desired batch file.

1. Dont include ".bat" in URL param,
   Rather append .bat in your runBatch() method,  to whatever file you get in the param 
   e.g.

   ```
   public ResultFormat runBatch(String fileName) {

   String var = fileName;
   String filePath = ("C:/Users/attsuap1/Desktop/" + var+".bat");
   try {
       Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath);
   ```
2. But if you do want to include .bat in your URl, you will have to use the below regex-mapping so that spring does not ignore the filename trailing the dot.

   ```
   @RequestMapping("/runbatchfileparam/{param:.+}")  
   public ResultFormat runbatchFile(@PathVariable("param") String fileName) 
   {  
   RunBatchFile rbf = new RunBatchFile();  
   return rbf.runBatch(fileName);  
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me ill try this

Comment: The batch files are not getting executed. If i use the first method, in the URL i just have to type `http://localhost:8080/runbatchfileparam/test123` without the `.bat` ? I tried that and still the batch file did not get executed

Comment: What error did you see? I think one more forward slash is missing in your
String filePath = ("C:/Users/attsuap1/Desktop"

After Desktop there should be "/"
String filePath = ("C:/Users/attsuap1/Desktop/"